# Изменение исходной булевой функции по правилу де Моргана в Prolog

Tags: prolog

Доброго дня.
Мне нужно написать программу на прологе, которая меняла бы участки выражения на эквивалентные по правилу де Моргана.
Сложность в том, что программа получает в качестве аргумента темр состоящий из функторов, которые в свою очередь содержат еще функторы.
Т.е. выражение вида ~(A v B) & (~(A & C) v D & B) подается в программу как
&(~(v(A,B)),v(~(&(A,C)),&(D,B))).
Однако у меня не выходит получить результат.

```
transform( ~ (XX & YY), ~XX v ~YY).
transform( ~ (XX v YY), ~XX & ~YY).

exp_transform(Term, Result_Term):-
  var(Term), var(Result_Term).

exp_transform(Term, Result_Term):-
  arg(_, Term, Value_Basic),
  arg(_, Result_Term, Value_of_ResTerm),
  exp_transform(Value_Basic, Value_of_ResTerm).

exp_transform(Term, Result_Term):-
  transform(Term, Result_Term),
  exp_transform(Term, Result_Term).
```

Перебирал различные варианты.
Можете подсказать в чем заключается проблема? Как подавать и обрабатывать выражение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как подавать и обрабатывать выражение?

Я, пожалуй, упроcтил бы синтаксис, заменив операторы обычными функторами

~ -> not,

& -> and,

v -> or.

```
 % Упростить булеву функцию    
reduce( X, Y ) :-
     transform( X, Y ), !.
 % Не упрощается, остаётся сама собой
reduce( X, X ).


% Двойное отрицание
transform( not( not( X )), X ).
% De Morgan 
transform( not( and( X, Y )), or( not( X ), not( Y ))).
% De Morgan 
transform( not( or( X, Y )), and( not( X ), not( Y ))).
% ......

Я использую SWI-Prolog.
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.  
Однако программа изменяет в небольшие выражения, если ввести  
 ~((x v z) & (x v y)) & (~(x & y) v t & u) как  
and(not((and(or(A,C), or(A,B)))), or(not(and(A,B)),and(D, E)), то программа выведет исходный терм т.к. не видит подвыражения.  
Я пытался решить эту проблему с помощью arg(), увы не вышло

Comment: @Volv58 если моё упрощение создает проблемы, то используйте Вашу нотацию, и всё! :)

Comment: Выражения можно также перекодировать на лету ( и обратно, если надо ), но, думаю, это лишнее. Если Вас всё-таки это заинтересовало, дайте знать.

Comment: Я справился с задачей, взяв за основу предложенное вами решение.
`transform( XX & YY v ZZ, (XX v ZZ) & (YY v ZZ)).  
transform( XX v YY & ZZ, (XX v YY) & (XX v ZZ)).  
transform( XX v YY, XX1 v YY):-
  transform( XX, XX1).
transform( XX v YY, XX v YY1):-  
  transform( YY, YY1).  
transform( XX & YY, XX1 & YY):-  
  transform( XX, XX1).  
transform( XX & YY, XX & YY1):-  
  transform( YY, YY1).`

Comment: Хорошо, только мне казалось что представление **transform** в виде фактов удобнее - не надо копировать  одни и те же тела правил. Может быть я ошибся с **reduce** ?

Comment: btw `arg(_, Term, Value_Basic),`
       `arg(_, Result_Term, Value_of_ResTerm),` некорректно. Я не помню -  `arg(-,+,+)` валидный режим для `arg/3`. В любом случае `_` - это не имя, а обозначение **анонимной** переменной . Они **разные**  и не передают значений. т.е. их надо заменить на норм. переменные.